# How can I sort this bar chart by total number of species?

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Bar Chart]

Above is the chart I created using `DataFrame.plot`. However, it's not really in my desired order. It should be in descending order based on the total number of species. Here is the code I wrote to create this.

```
## Group data by park_name and conservation status
cons_park = park_species.groupby(['park_name', 'conservation_status']).scientific_name.count().reset_index()
pivoted_cons_park = pd.pivot_table(
    data=cons_park, index='park_name',
    columns='conservation_status',
    values='scientific_name'
)

## Sort data based on conservation status - Changing this one will result in a different chart
pivoted_cons_park.sort_values(by='Species of Concern', inplace=True)

## Plot a bar chart to visualize the data
pivoted_cons_park.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(10,10))
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1.01))
plt.title('Species in Conservation in US National Parks', weight='bold')
plt.ylabel('Park', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Number of species', fontsize=12)
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sorting your dataframe by the value "Species of Concern". You should add another column representing the total number of species, and then sort by that value. While plotting you could keep that column hidden.

Comment: So you mean that I should create an extra column for the total number of species? Thanks. I may give it a try.

Comment: @JettChenT Much appreciated. It works and everything looks good now.